# How to add text in a txt file with bash scripting

Tags: bash

i have a question. I need to add a text line into a txt file. This is my file:

- 000
- 001 test1
- 002 test2
- 003 test3
- 004
- 005 test4
- 006 test5
- 007 test6

I need with bash scripting to add text in line 000 and 004.

How can i do?
Thanks to all!

Comment: Are the numbers actually present in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "sed" tool to acheive your goal. It is quite powerful for manipulating files.
You can use a command like this:

```
sed -i /your/file.txt -e "s/000/000'\n'YOUR_NEW_LINE/"
sed -i /your/file.txt -e "s/004/004'\n'YOUR_NEW_LINE/"
```

(If I understand correctly, you have "000" at the begining of the first line of your file, and "004" for the fifth one)

Comment: Ok thank you so much this work. But i have a problem, i need to inseret new line in fisrt blanck line. How i can do? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: The number of line is posted by gedit, but in file there aren't line number

Answer (score 1):

That's what the [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) and [`ed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ed) utilities are for. They use the same set of commands with some minor differences. Major difference is that `ed` edits a file and takes commands on standard input while `sed` takes commands on command-line and edits standard input to standard output.

Using `sed` is usually more convenient except when you hit something that it can't do due to it's streaming nature like moving text around.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in native bash with a while/read loop:

```
while read num cmt; do
  if [[ -z cmt ]] ; then
    printf '%s test%s\n' "$num" "$num"
  else
    echo "$num $num"
  fi
done <infile.txt >outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==1{print $0, "Foo"}NR==5{print $0, "Bar"}'
```